# Changing Font Awesome Button Style onClick

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

I have a button styled as a Font Awesome.

```
              <button
                onClick={this.changeLockButtonStyle}
                id="LockButton"
                >
                <FaLockOpen />
              </button>
```

I'm trying to find a way to change the style to `<FaLockClosed />` From reading up online the only examples I see are regarding JQuery and class=”fas fa-lockclosed” toggle class. But I am using a button, not the normal icon. I have tried `document.getElementById('LockButton').innerHTML= '<FaLockClosed />'` but doesnt work. I'd like to avoid using JQuery if possible.

Comment: have you tried just removing the current class and replacing it with a new one to change the style?

Comment: @Souhailhimself But the example above is not setting the class no? Its set up using the npm install of FA. I just tried your solution and used the stylesheet and 
```
<button
                onClick={this.changeLockButton}
                id="LockButton"
                >
                <i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i> 
              </button>
```
However, no icon shows, its an empty button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useState(false);

return (
    <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => { setIsLocked(true); }}
    >
        {isLocked ? <FaLockClose /> : <FaLockOpen />}
    </button>
);
```

Update:
Thats how you do it in class component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLocked: false
    };

    this.lockIcon = this.lockIcon.bind(this);
}

lockIcon() {
    this.setState({ isLocked: true });
}

render() {
    const { isLocked } = this.state;

    return (
        <button
            type="button"
            onClick={this.lockIcon}
        >
            {isLocked ? <FaLockClose /> : <FaLockOpen />}
        </button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Where does `const [isLocked, setIsLocked] = useState(false);` go? I am getting invalid hook error if placing it above the class.

Comment: In class component you do it different way. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. Will I be able to use this for multiple buttons? Will I just need to add multiple "locked" states to the constructor?

Comment: Depends from your needs. If one click should lock all the buttons: yes. If click should lock specific button, then you need to declare the separate state for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

My best practice solution is using css class.
But if you can't do it , you can use display state for the 2 icons that controlled by a javascript variable.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you using react or angular, I would just toggle the component depending on a variable set during button pushed.

Reference on how to do the toggle in react
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425155/14167216

Here is a jQuery example.
You can set the class on the button and then check if button has class. If it has lock class then change to unlock class, and vice-versa. Check the sample code below.

```js
function changeLockButtonStyle() {
  var icon = $('#LockButton')
  var hasLock = icon.hasClass('fa-lock');
  if(hasLock) {
     icon.removeClass('fa-lock').addClass('fa-unlock');
  } else {
     icon.removeClass('fa-unlock').addClass('fa-lock');
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button
      onClick='changeLockButtonStyle()'
      id="LockButton"
      class="fa fa-lock"
    >
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably going to go this route, but is it possible without JQuery?

Comment: You could try to do raw javascript like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824723/14167216 or similarly like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26736704/14167216

Comment: If using react or angular, just toggle the component depending on a variable set to falsy or thuthy on button clicked